# GEtting Error: Attribute error class object has no attribute

Tags: python, oop

I am relatively new to python and to OOP. I have been trying to create a function that creates a class based on the inputs of said function. I assume the class and the object are created since I get no errors. The thing is that when I try to access a field by its attribute i get the "AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute...", and can catch why. Is there something wrong with the approach to the problem? Any help is appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
def make_class(*args):
    class Class:
        def __init__(self,*args):
            for i,e in enumerate(args):
                setattr(self, "{}".format(e), e)
    return Class

Animal=make_class("name", "species", "age", "health", "weight", "color")
dog1=Animal("Bob","Dog",5,"good","50lb","brown")
dog1.name
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#112>", line 1, in <module>
    dog1.name
AttributeError: 'Class' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the `args` being passed into `make_class`. The `args` of `Class.__init__` are going to be whatever you pass in when you instantiate the `Animal(...)`. `dog1` will have an attribute named `Bob` which will be set to `"Bob"`, etc.

Comment: If you're new to Python, this seems like a strange exercise. Creating classes dynamically is a relatively advanced topic. Few programmers ever have need to do this kind of meta-programming. This is the kind of thing that modules like `dataclass` and `attr` do, and the rest of us just make use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same name `args` for the arguments to `make_class()` and `__init__()`. Your code is just using the `__init__()` arguments.

You should iterate over the two argument lists in parallel, so they need different names.

```
def make_class(*attr_names):
    class Class:
        def __init__(self,*args):
            for name, value in zip(attr_names, args):
                setattr(self, name, value)
    return Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! It worked for  me. I guess i got a lot to learn. Tank you